# Using wget to target files within a date range

Tags: date, wget

I'm using `wget` to download some log files from a remote server.
Is it possible to use `wget` to target files using date ranges (based
on the last modified file header) ?
For example:

```
wget --after-date=03112014 http://foo/bar
```

Comment: Did you check the manual page `man wget` ?

Comment: Well, I found some interesting info about mirroring and timestamping. But, what I want is targetting by date.

Comment: I think it's not possible, see the mailing list: [Timestamping but ignore files older than?](https://www.mail-archive.com/wget@sunsite.dk/msg09667.html)

Answer (score 1):

curl has an option,

From the manual page !

> -z/--time-cond
>
> (HTTP/FTP) Request a file that has been modified later than the
>   given   time  and  date, or  one  that has been modified before that
>   time. The   date expression can be all sorts of date strings or if it
>   doesn't match   any internal ones, it tries  to  get  the  time from 
>   a given file name   instead! See the curl_getdate(3) man pages for
>   date expression details.
>
> Start the date expression with a dash (-) to make it request for   a
>   document  that  is older than the given date/time, default is a
>   document that is newer than the specified date/time.
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.